# Is Hibernate @JoinColumn(nullable = false) redundant if not used for DDL generation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Some of our entities declare `OneToMany` / `OneToOne` Relationships with `nullable = false`

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
private List<Things> manyThings;
```

We use Flyway for DDLs. I have read in many sources that the `JoinColumn` property `nullable` is only used for DDL generation - so do I understand correctly that when our Flyway Scripts generate Tables with Constraints on the DB directly, the `nullable = false` property on our Entities is redundant? What exactly is meant by DDL-Generation and what does Hibernate offer in this regard?

I came across this problem because on some tables it turned out that the constraint on the DB Columns were `Non-Null = true` whereas on the Java Entities the property `nullable = false` was set. This didn't seem to have any effect on the application at runtime; it would happily insert `null` values. However, when running a SpringBootTest it would fail with a constraint violation.

Comment: Sounds like you are using an existing database in one case and a test or in memory database like H2DB in the second case. In the second case the DDL is being generated and the database is created each time you run. You should know what database DDL is. Hibernate EntityManager has routines for generating DDL to files or you can turn on show the SQL in the SpringBootTest and see the DDL being created and applied.

Comment: no, in both cases we are using an Oracle Database. In both cases Flyway is creating the Tables.

Comment: hey enp4yne any updates on that? Did my answer below help you somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It's not only for DDL generation, but also for Hibernate validation annotations.

When you say *nullable = false*, JPA generates database constraints (not-null) and ALSO generate a [JSR 303 Bean Validation](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) that don't let you persist the entity if the *nullable = false* column is null in Runtime. So, when you write *nullable = false*, JPA generates those two features for the price of one. *@Column(nullable = false)* is the JPA way of declaring a column to be not-null.

With nullable = false, the following save shall fail:

```
ObjectThatContainsListThings a = new ObjectThatContainsListThings();
a.setListOfThings(null)

hibernate.persist(a);
DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

JPA will throw this exception instead of letting the database find the problem.